PAM Login Service Authentication Failure for other users (Debian Bookworm)
I have an node-express api application that's running as a service where I implemented a PAM authentication using authenticate-pam and node-linux-pam' library. Whenever I call the /login endpoint it fails for other users but not this {ok-user}. I tried calling the endpoint using a react app (main & simple), postman and curl - fails for other user and success for {ok-user}.
This {ok-user} is what I'm using to the run the services. The issue is that the pam authentication for other users fails except {ok-user}. I already checked and the other users are authenticated or present using pamtester, grep the users in /etc/shadow & /etc/passwd, and login in the terminal via ssh.
I did not add any special configuration for {ok-user} and I also re-installed pam.d to reset the configurations but the issue still persist.
The main issue is that it can find the user but can't authenticate the password via the API PAM authentication.
This is the only log details I can get when the auth fails. I tried a lot of ways to get more details but nothing worked.
2024-11-20T11:36:22.218288+11:00 {ok-user} node: pam_unix(login:auth): username [testuser] obtained
2024-11-20T11:36:22.288307+11:00 {ok-user} unix_chkpwd[13274]: check pass; user unknown
2024-11-20T11:36:22.349069+11:00 {ok-user} unix_chkpwd[13275]: check pass; user unknown
2024-11-20T11:36:22.350108+11:00 {ok-user} unix_chkpwd[13275]: password check failed for user (testuser)
2024-11-20T11:36:22.351009+11:00 {ok-user} node: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1001 euid=1001 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=testuser

When the auth succeeds this is what I get only.
2024-11-20T11:37:44.293536+11:00 {ok-user} node: pam_unix(login:auth): username [{ok-user}] obtained

Also, when the common-auth is configured like this it fails for all users, but it does not log an authentication failure message for {ok-user}, only for others.
auth    required      pam_unix.so nullok_secure debug
...

If the configuration is like this it does not fail for {ok-user}.
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok debug
...

Below is my pam authentication logic in the api. This uses PAM login service automatically.
/ PAM Authentication function
function authenticateWithPAM(username, password, callback) {
  pam.authenticate(username, password, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return callback(false); // Authentication failed
      }
      callback(true); // Authentication successful
  });
}

Thank you in advance for your help.
